# How would I remove blank characters from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

How would I remove blank characters from a string in JavaScript?

A trim is very easy, but I don't know how to remove them from *inside* the string. For example:

`222 334 -> 222334`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nick Craver has a good response, if you're OK with regex, go for it.

I just want to add that you can do this without Regex as well.  You can just use a normal JavaScript replace(), using the parameters (" ", "") to replace all whitespace with empty strings.

**Update**: Whoops, this won't work with multiple whitespaces.

[JavaScript replace method on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Comment: This will also only replace the *first* occurrence of a space, not all of them.

Comment: Stefan: If tabs need to be pulled as well, then of course, Nick Craver's regex is best.

Comment: Thanks Cyrena, I have to add also that you are very beautiful

Answer (score 50):

You can use a regex, like this to replace all whitespace:

```
var oldString = "222 334";
var newString = oldString.replace(/\s+/g,"");
```

Or for literally *just* spaces:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/ /g,"");
```

Comment: This will work for most use cases, however not for unicode space characters.

Answer (score 14):

You can also do this without a regular expression or a replace-

```
var string= string.split(' ').join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `trim()`.

See docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp).