# Remove spaces in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I'm using AJAX to retrieve data from MYSQL database through PHP.

However, if there is no result found, the variable still has two spaces. I found the problem using `alert(data.length);`. The result is **2**, which means there are two spaces.

How can I remove these spaces so that if there is no result, I could display a message using `if(data == ''){}`?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846978/remove-characters-from-a-string) and [How remove blank characters from a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893625/how-remove-blank-characters-from-a-string-in-javascript).

Comment: If I were you, I would [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) the response on the PHP end.

Comment: @bfavaretto - I tried to do so, but I don't know, query passes through if($query) even query is empty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called string trimming. And here is one option for that in pure JavaScript:

```
var len = data.replace(/\s/g, "").length;
```

However, in modern browsers there is a string [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function for that:

```
var len = data.trim().length;
```

Comment: but I don't want to remove spaces if there are some results, then spaces in those results will be also removed..I can try, if data.length == 2 then i can trim it..  thank you for ur answer...

Answer (score 3):

I can't understand why you have those two empty spaces in the first place.
If it's a suitable option for you, I would try to remove those spaces at the origin, so from the server response.

If that's not possible you could use `String.prototype.trim` to remove leading/trailing white space. This would allow you to write your check as below

```
if (data.trim().length === 0) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "lots of whitespace";
str.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // 'lotsofwhitespace'
```

Answer (score 1):

See this post where the [topic is covered deeply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript), if you use jQuery, you can use `$.trim()` which is built-in.

Answer (score 1):

if your variable is `data` then try this

```
    data.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

and assign it to other variable if you want

```
data2 = data.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

3 options:

```
var strg = "there is space";
strg.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

or:

```
$.trim()
```

or:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() { 
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); 
}

var strg = "there is space";
strg.trim();
```

Comment: but I don't want to remove spaces if there are any results, then spaces in those results will be also removed.. now I can do if data.length == 2 then trim it using ur way.. thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

`data = data.split(' ').join('')` that will remove all spaces from a string.